# Conditional Rendering for specific component in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a component which looks like this:

```
<section class="page-layout__section {{ skin }}">
   <header class="page-layout__header">
    <ng-content *ngIf="!showHeader" select="[page-layout-header]"></ng-content>
    <ng-content *ngIf="!showHeader" select="[page-layout-subheader]"></ng-content>
  </header>
</section>
```

And below is the `.ts` file:

```
    import { Component, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

type PageLayoutType = 'default' | 'cards' | 'grid' | 'settings';
export type Skin = 'default' | 'classic' | 'control-hub-2020';

@Component({
  selector: 'webex-page-layout',
  templateUrl: './page-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-layout.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class PageLayoutComponent {
  @Input() pageLayoutScrollableContent = true;
  @Input() showHeader = true;
  @Input() pageLayoutType: PageLayoutType = 'default';
  @Input() skin: Skin = 'default';
}
```

I want to do a conditional rendering for the header component. The **selector** for this component is `webex-page-layout`.So in the parent component I created a variable for the conditional  rendering and passed it as :

```
<webex-page-layout [showHeader]="showHeader" class="gray">
 </webex-page-layout>
```

And in the `.ts` file, I added the vairable :

```
 public showHeader = true;

public showAnalysisEvent(type: string) {
    this.showHeader = false;
    this.sendMetrics(CCUC_TS_EVENTS.LOG_COLLECTION_STATE, {
      state: PageConstant.SHOW,
    });
    this.sendMetrics(CCUC_TS_EVENTS.ANALYSIS_REPORT_OPENED, {
      reportType: AnalysisReportType.OPENED + type,
    });
  }
```

But, its not working as expected. Please help.

Comment: You are using ng-content, but not setting anything inside your child tag, what do you expect will show there if you have nothing?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what `ng-content` does and what content projection is. I suggest you read up on it :) https://angular.io/guide/content-projection

Answer (score 0):

what do you spect to work this? I see you want to show or not header and subheader, all of the header component show or hide base on your showHeader?

```
<ng-content *ngIf="!showHeader" select="[page-layout-header]"></ng-content>
<ng-content *ngIf="!showHeader" select="[page-layout-subheader]"></ng-content>
```

in that code you show that ng-contents only if showHeader is false, both of them, (!showHeader = showHeader false).

Be specific about what you expect to happen for each scenario

Update base on your comment:
Change ng-content with ng-template and try again, also try with double !! like this:

```
<ng-template *ngIf="!!showHeader" select="[page-layout-header]"></ng-template >
<ng-template *ngIf="!!showHeader" select="[page-layout-subheader]"></ng-template>
```

Comment: In the parent component, I have changed the state of the showHeader variable in the function event click and set it to false, so I want to show the header and subheader only when the showHeader is true. I did try doing `<ng-content *ngIf="showHeader" select="[page-layout-header]"></ng-content>` for both of them ,but that's still not working